# How to align text to left on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, devops, pipeline, text-align

I accidentally pressed something and now when I try to create a new project in Jenkins everything is aligned to the middle.. how can I align everything back to the left?
I tried to restart Jenkins, I even updated it to a newer version but nothing fixed it
[image]

Comment: My guess is an issue from [tables to divs migration](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/developer/views/table-to-div-migration/) and what appears to be non-english SCM plugin compatibility. Follow the instructions to disable plugins to identify. Also try switching to English locale to see if it goea away. If not already [reported](https://issues.jenkins.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa?selectPageId=20741) a JIRA issue against affected plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be very similar to what you have.
https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-65790
"This issue was resolved by disabling the rbenv plugin."